# How to redirect to URL by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have JavaScript code to redirect to URL but it doesn't work. It will load but no redirect to the URL. The page which have this code the content of data for Facebook tab front page.

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function newDoc() {
        window.location.assign("http://facebookapp.elarabygroup.com/facebook_login.aspx")
    }
</script>
```

The page:

```
 <a onclick="newDoc()" >
            <img src="images/glass.png" width="95" height="72" />play now</a>
```

Comment: what happens? Hit F12 to open the console, any errors?

Comment: I'm wondering why you put a C# tag on this.

Comment: @fred02138 the href tag in aspx page

Comment: @epascarello i have this error Uncaught ReferenceError: bmi_load is not defined

Comment: Well you need to show more code.

Comment: If the code is in in IFRAME, it may be the page in question refuses to load inside an IFRAME.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location` instead of `window.location.assign`

For instance this will redirect you to example.com when you click the text. (Tested in Chrome)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onClick() {
            window.location = "http://example.com";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a onclick="onClick()">To example.com!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, window.location.href='http//:www.google.com '  it will generate a new request.